Puedo usar JavaScript para leer parámetros pasados por un servlet Java?
He pensado en pasar los parámetros a la URL como "https://example.com?dato1=valor1&dato2=valor2", pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto de los servlets y creo que así podría o no?

Me faltan detalles: quieres añadir datos a la URL o quieres leer de la URL con javascript?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
